# How to discretize hour-times?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have some time values that I am trying to discretize according to 3 categories: morning (4.30, 12.00), evening(12.00, 21.00), night(21.00, 4.30)

First I am trying to convert the character vector into a character using lubridate

```
library(lubridate)
h <- hm(c("14:30", "02:10", "06:30", "14:50", "20:30", "21:00", "12:00", "23:30", "08:10", "00:00"))
```

Now I need to discretize `h`.

I would normally use `cut`, but it doesn't seem to work here:

```
cut(h, breaks = hm(c('4.30', '12.00', '21.00')), levels = c('morning', 'evening', 'night'))
```

Is there a specific function in lubridate?

Comment: `h` is a period of time. It is not time. eg h can be 14 hours and 30 mins from now etc. So you will have to first convert to a date time then use `cut`

Comment: Discretizing the period of time would work too. I understand it's not the best way, but how do I coerce to time type without adding a date then?

Comment: What do you mean discretizing a period would work? Eg. Tell me you have a period of 10hours how would you discretize that? what if its 10 hours from midnight or 10 hours from midday or 10 hours from 6pm. So the period 10hours how will you discretize it??

Comment: You will have to add the date, although it wont have an impact since you will be dealing with time. Just ensure all the times have the same date

Comment: @Onyambu something like `h <- cut(c(1, 24), breaks = c(0, 4, 21, 24))`
`levels(h) <- c('night', 'morning', 'night')`

Comment: According to your labels, what should be '02:10' or '23:30'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can convert it to `times` object

```
library(chron)
t1 <- times(paste0(v1, ":00"))
```

and then do the `cut` by specifying the `breaks` as `times`

```
cut(t1, breaks = times(c('04:30:00', '12:00:00', 
            '21:00:00', '21:00:01')), labels = c('morning', 'evening', 'night'))
#[1] evening <NA>    morning evening evening evening morning <NA>    morning <NA>   
#Levels: morning evening night

#Levels: morning evening night
```

---

Or this can be done with `strptime` from `base R`

```
res <- cut(strptime(v1, format = "%H:%M"), breaks = strptime(c("04:30", "12:00", 
   "21:00", "21:01"), format = "%H:%M"), 
   labels = c("morning", "evening", "night"))
res[is.na(res)] <- "night"
res
#[1] evening night   morning evening evening night   evening night   morning night  
#Levels: morning evening night
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("14:30", "02:10", "06:30", "14:50", "20:30",
            "21:00", "12:00", "23:30", "08:10", "00:00")
```

Comment: Please check your output. `t[1]` is given the output of `night`

Comment: @Onyambu  It is based on the OP's label.  Please check his code

Comment: The first solution has an `NA`

Comment: @Dambo It is because I didn't do an an assignment.  as in the second one.  If `res` is the first solution, just do `res[is.na(res)] <- "night"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findInterval` from base R:

```
breaks=strptime(c("0.00","4.00","12.00","21.00","23.59"),"%H.%M")
labels=c("night","morning","evening","night")
labels[findInterval(strptime(dat,"%H:%M"),breaks)]
 [1] "evening" "night"   "morning" "evening" "evening" "night"   "evening"
 [8] "night"   "morning" "night"
```

Where

```
 dat <- c("14:30", "02:10", "06:30", "14:50", "20:30",
        "21:00", "12:00", "23:30", "08:10", "00:00")
```

We can see that dat 2 has been given `night`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to turn the times into numbers, and then you can use the discretize function in arules. This can be flexible and used with dates etc.

```
require(arules)
h <- data.frame(V1=(c("14:30", "02:10", "06:30", "14:50", "20:30", "21:00", "12:00", "23:30", "08:10", "00:00")))
h$V2<- gsub("\\:", "", h$V1)
h$discrete=discretize(h$V2,method="fixed",categories=c(0,1430,1200,2100,Inf))
```